# Chrome extensions: execute script on current tab after receiving response from the api call (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

After clicking on a button on a `default_popup` html file, I want to execute API endpoint and inject (execute) a script with the API response to the current tab.

Executing a script without waiting for API response worked fine:

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(activeTabs) {
        chrome.scripting
            .executeScript({
                target : {tabId : activeTabs[0].id},
                func : foo,
        })
        .then(() => finally());

        
    });
});
```

But when I want to the the same, just after the api response is fetched:

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', async function() {

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8888/get-data");
    const content = await response.json();

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(activeTabs) {
        chrome.scripting
            .executeScript({
                target : {tabId : activeTabs[0].id},
                func : foo(content),
        })
        .then(() => finally());

        
    });
});
```

The script is not executed inside a current tab, but inside the popup itself, so waiting for response somehow messes up the chrome's injection logic. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Query the URL of the main document instead of active tab.

Comment: Another option is not using a popup at all and just use `chrome.action.onClicked`.

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for suggestions, but I cannot execute the URL from the context where I'm injecting a script to, because of the CORS. And I need a popup as a user interface to execute the logic on button click.

Comment: Your mistake is `foo(content)` which is a call and not a reference to the function. It should be just `foo` and you need to add `,args: [content]`, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection).

Comment: @wOxxOm That's it, thanks a lot! I'd be happy to tick your answer if you're willing to post it.